# Ansible not working with sudo

Tags: sudo, ansible

I am trying to use ansible, but I seem to not be able to get it to work with sudo. I have minimised the problem to this:

This does not work:

```
ansible localhost --ask-become-pass -m shell  -a "cat  /var/log/syslog"
```

Gives this output: I type password, then it errors.

```
SUDO password:
localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
cat: /var/log/syslog: Permission denied
```

These work fine:

```
ssh -t localhost sudo cat /var/log/syslog #without ansible
ansible localhost -m shell -a "ls" #without sudo
```

Other diagnostics:

```
#expecting last line to be `root`
ansible localhost  --become-user=root --ask-become-pass -m shell  -a "whoami"
```

gives this output, when correct password entered.

```
SUDO password:
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
richard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `--ask-become-pass` is not enough, you also need the `--become` param. Therefore the command is: `ansible localhost  --become --ask-become-pass -m shell  -a "cat /var/log/syslog"`.

I have also noticed that I do not need `--ask-become-pass`, I think the password is being cached, like `sudo` does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this to the command when you run `--ask-become-pass`

So, `ansible yoga  --become-user=root --ask-become-pass -m shell  -a "cat  /var/log/syslog"`

Comment: `--become-user=root`, did not help (no change). And the manual says it defaults to root.